# TIBCO BW 6.5 Debug error "qualifier bundle name: Application_Name.module " which needs to be resolved"

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

I am trying to debug an application in TIBCO BW 6.5, while debugging the application I am facing the error as:-

ERROR com.tibco.bw.thor.runtime.model.Constituent - The following error has occurred for "name: Application_Name.module version: 1.0.0.qualifier bundle name: Application_Name.module " which needs to be resolved.
Failed to start BW Application [Application_Name] due to exception [com.tibco.bx.core.faults.BxException]

Can anyone tell me why this error occurs and how to resolve this?

Comment: You can use OSGi command "la" to have more details about the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you resolve this issue:-

1) Delete your Component binding (copy all your values first) and then recreate the same binding with same values as before. Then clean your projects.

2) Delete if some "Dependencies" are there in Module Descriptor, and then add them again. Clean your projects. Now run your application

3) If above doesn't work then try changing your workspace.

Thank you,
Rudra